# Weird, extra margin with float layout

Tags: html, css, layout

I'm trying to setup a simple layout that is constituted with two columns,

One floats to the left, like a sidebar. The other naturally "floats" to the right side, by setting a left margin.

(I wanted to horizontally align the two elements)

But I got an extra margin on top of the left element, as seen in this picture:

[image]

Attached source code [(Or the jsfiddle link)](http://jsfiddle.net/SXtz5/)

```
<html><head>
        <style>
        .leftbar {
            float: left;
        }
        .userinfo-meta {
            border: 3px solid #666;
            min-height: 300px;
        }
        .post {
            min-height: 100px;
            margin-left: 21%;
            width: 60%;
            border: 3px solid #876;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="post">This element should be on the same level as the right</div>
    <div class="userinfo-meta leftbar">This one floats to the left</div>
</body></html>
```

P.S I can't use a negative margin-top for the left element, the height of the other element 
varies ... If that changes, the margin-top need to be adjusted again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change the order in the HTML markup like this :

```
<div class="userinfo-meta leftbar">This one floats to the left</div>
<div class="post">This element should be on the same level as the right</div>
```

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/SXtz5/10/)**

Answer (score 0):

Adding the margin meant the divs wouldn't go that way. If you `float` the `.post` div right you don't need to `float` the `.leftbar` div to the left, you can if you want.

Add `float:right` and remove `margin-left` to the `.post` CSS:

```
    .post {
        min-height: 100px;
        width: 60%;
        border: 3px solid #876;
        float:right;
    }
```

See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vagish/SXtz5/9/

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="post">
        This element should be on the same level as the right
    </div>
    <div class="leftbar">This one floats to the left</div>
</div>

* {
    box-sizing:border-box;
}

.wrapper:before, .wrapper:after{
    display:table;
    content:"";
}

.wrapper:after{
    clear:both;
}

.leftbar {
    border: 3px solid #876;
    width:40%;
    float:left;
}

.post {
    min-height: 100px;
    width: 60%;
    border: 3px solid #876;
    float:right;
}
```

And if you want same height left & right column.you can try with display:table class.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should slightly update your HTML:

```
  <html>
    <head>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="post">
        <div class="internal">
        This element should be on the same level as the right
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="userinfo-meta leftbar">
        <div class="internal">This one floats to the left</div>
    </div>
</body>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/SXtz5/6/
(there you can see CSS - also slightly different).

Then you can adjust any padding/margin with .internal div.